# How to access EventBridge in private subnet without VPC Endpoint?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-vpc, aws-event-bridge

I use this sdk `import com.amazonaws.services.eventbridge.model.PutEventsRequest;` to publish event to AWS EventBridge. I deployed this application on ECS.

The ECS is on a private subnet and cannot access the public internet. Due to security issues, we are not allowed to access Internet.

**Also, there is no VPC Endpoint for Eventbridge in China region.**

So, how to publish the event to EventBridge without changing too many codes and without the Internet?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use NAT gateway.

Comment: @Marcin Due to the security issue, we cannot access public Internet.